# Common Lisp: What does #+nil?

Tags: common-lisp

The other day (perhaps yesterday) I was quite perplexed about this `#+nil` read-time conditional found in https://github.com/billstclair/defperson/blob/master/defperson.lisp#L289.

After some deep thinking I came to the conclusion that this is very lispy way of *commenting out* code. Can someone confirm this?

Perhaps my assumptions are completely wrong. Anyway, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [CLHS 2.4.8.17 Sharpsign Plus](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhq.htm)

To conditionalize reading expressions from input, Common Lisp uses feature [expressions](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/24_aba.htm).

**In this case it has been used to comment out a form.**

It's a part of the reader. `#+`  looks if the next item, usually as a keyword symbol with the same name, is a member of the list `*features*`. If yes, the then next item is read as normal, if not, it is skipped.. Usually `:NIL` is not a member of that list, so the item is skipped. Thus it hides the expression from Lisp. There might have been a Lisp implementation, where this would not work : *NIL*, *New Implementation of Lisp*. It might have had the symbol `:NIL` on the `*features*` list, to indicate the name of the implementation.

Features like `NIL` are by default read in the `keyword` package:

- `#+NIL`  -> looks for `:NIL` in `cl:*features*`
- `#+CL:NIL`  -> looks for `CL:NIL` in `cl:*features*`

**Example**

```
(let ((string1 "#+nil foo bar"))             ; string to read from

  (print (read-from-string string1))         ; read from the string

  (let ((*features* (cons :nil *features*))) ; add :NIL to *features*
    (print (read-from-string string1)))      ; read from the string

  (values))                                  ; return no values
```

It prints:

```
BAR 
FOO
```

Note that Common Lisp has other ways to comment out forms:

```
; (sin 3) should we use that?

#| (sin 3)  should we use that?
   (cos 3)  or this?            |#
```

Comment: As a note; it looks like `SBCL` ignores `#+nil ...` expressions even when `NIL` **is** in `*features*`. If written in a file, then loaded, the following prints "Nope": `(push nil *features*) #+nil (format t "NIL is in *features*") #-nil (format t "Nope")`.

Comment: @Inaimathi that is because the feature expression is read into the keyword package. `:NIL` would be the relevant symbol in `*features*`.

Comment: @m-n: Yup. Replacing the first expression above with `(push :nil *features*) ...` prints `NIL is in *features*`.

Answer (score 6):

[Yes, it is a lispy way of commenting code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6365579/800524), but you shouldn't leave this out in production code.

A better alternative is `#+(or)`.

It only takes one more character, it takes the same key presses if you use Emacs paredit or some other mode that automatically inserts the closing parenthesis, and it's not subject to the existence of the symbol `:nil` in `*features*`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. If I had found this earlier I wouldn't had to post my question, but `#+nil` is really hard to search for.

Comment: Even better, though (at least in my opinion), is `#-(and)`, because the `#-` seems more like commenting something out than `#+` does.

Comment: I sometimes use `#+#:ignore` if I'm feeling paranoid.