# What is the meaning of #+: and #-: in common lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, reader-macro

I am reading the [cl-fad/load.lisp](https://github.com/edicl/cl-fad/blob/master/load.lisp) code tonight, and I found there are symbols `#+:` and `#-:` in the front of expression or string.

What's these symbols meaning?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29849954/124319

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are a read-time conditionalization facility: [`#+`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhq.htm) and [`#-`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhr.htm) let you decide what expression to [`read`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) based on [Feature Expressions](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/24_aba.htm).

E.g.,

```
#+:allegro (require :osi)
#+:sbcl (require :sb-executable)
```

means that when running under `allegro`, the module `:osi` will be loaded, but when running under `sbcl`, the module `:sb-executable` will be loaded by [`require`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_provid.htm).

Under all other implementations [`require`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_provid.htm) will not be called at all because [`read`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) will skip over the forms.

You can check not just the implementation name, but a specific feature, e.g.,

```
#+(<= (integer-length most-positive-fixnum) 32)
code for a 32-bit lisp
#+(> (integer-length most-positive-fixnum) 32)
code for a 64-bit lisp
```

In addition to selecting code based on implementation, this allows one to easily "comment out" a section of your code (i.e., the next sexp):

```
#+(or) (this code will be skipped over by any lisp reader
        because (or) returns nil)
```

Comment: For the "commenting out" I've also found `#+nil` to work.

Comment: @rogual: it only works because you are not using the [NIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIL_(programming_language))

Answer (score 2):

This are reader macros based on the list *features*, this macros indicates to execute a form or not if the symbol is present on the *features* list

Showing the features list:

```
CL-USER> *features*
(:SWANK :QUICKLISP :QUICKLISP-SUPPORT-HTTPS :ROS.INIT :ASDF-PACKAGE-SYSTEM :ASDF3.1 :ASDF3 :ASDF2 :ASDF :OS-MACOSX :OS-UNIX :ASDF-UNICODE :PRIMARY-CLASSES :COMMON-LISP :OPENMCL :CCL :CCL-1.2 :CCL-1.3 :CCL-1.4 :CCL-1.5 :CCL-1.6 :CCL-1.7 :CCL-1.8 :CCL-1.9 :CCL-1.10 :CCL-1.11 :CLOZURE :CLOZURE-COMMON-LISP :ANSI-CL :UNIX :OPENMCL-UNICODE-STRINGS :IPV6 :OPENMCL-NATIVE-THREADS :OPENMCL-PARTIAL-MOP :MCL-COMMON-MOP-SUBSET :OPENMCL-MOP-2 :OPENMCL-PRIVATE-HASH-TABLES :STATIC-CONSES-SHOULD-WORK-WITH-EGC-IN-CCL :X86-64 :X86_64 :X86-TARGET :X86-HOST :X8664-TARGET :X8664-HOST :DARWIN-HOST :DARWIN-TARGET :DARWINX86-TARGET :DARWINX8664-TARGET :DARWINX8664-HOST :64-BIT-TARGET :64-BIT-HOST :DARWIN :LITTLE-ENDIAN-TARGET :LITTLE-ENDIAN-HOST)
```

In my case I 'm running:

```
CL-USER> (lisp-implementation-type)
"Clozure Common Lisp"

CL-USER> (lisp-implementation-version)
"Version 1.11-r16635  (DarwinX8664)"
```

Let's execute the form if I'm using CCL

```
CL-USER> #+CCL (1+ 1)
2
```

It works, because I have CCL on the *features* list

```
CL-USER> #-CCL (1+ 1)
; No value
```

It doest work because I have CCL in the features list

Or you can think the oppsite,only execute if I dont' have in teh *features* list

```
CL-USER> #-calimero (1+ 1)
2
```

You can ad any symbol :word to the features list and you can also add logic

let's execute if I'm on the CCL and using a darwin host (i.e MAC OS X)

```
CL-USER> #+(and ccl darwin-host) (1+ 1)
```