# How to comment out chunk of code in Pact?

Tags: atom-editor, pact-lang

How do I comment out a chunk of code in Pact? Is there a shortcut in Atom for this?

I have tried `command+?` but it comments it out in HTML format.

This does however work in Pact Web (pact.kadena.io)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pact is a Lisp-like language and so makes use of Lisp-style comments using semicolons (but not block comments). For example, if you wanted to comment out some pact code, you could do the following

```
(my-module 'my-keys
  ;(hello-world-old:string (name:string)
  ;  ...)

  (hello-world-new:string (name:string)
    ...)
)
```

You can make use of semicolons in really expressive ways, which are detailed in this great post here: [Lisp commenting convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365334/lisp-commenting-convention)

Cheers, and happy hacking!

Comment: So just for clarity - there is no block commenting in Pact in Atom currently. Is this shortcut enabled by the linter? https://atom.io/packages/language-pact or does this get built into the language?

Comment: It's built into the language. You can use ';' for all your commenting needs.

Comment: It's true that `language-pact` does not integrate with Cmd-K yet, a PR is welcome! https://github.com/kadena-io/pact-atom